# Null pointer error?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, dialog

I am making a game, I have got several different classes as I dont like to put everything in one. I have a GameView class and a players class. The problem is that I am calling a method in players class from GameView. But its giving me an null pointer error. Below is my code:

GameVie class:

```
Panel p2 = new Panel();
p2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JLabel player1Lbl = new JLabel("Player 1");
p2.add(player1Lbl, BorderLayout.WEST);
player.enterNameP1(); //Having an error here.
player1Lbl.setText(player.enterNameP1());
```

Players Class:

```
public class Players
{
    //storing the player 1 name
    private String p1name;
    //storing the player 2 name
    private String p2name;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Players
     */
    public Players()
    {
        this.p1name = p1name;
        this.p2name = p2name;
    }

    /**
     *Enter the player 1 name in a dialog box
     */
    public String enterNameP1() //It was public void before but it wasnt accepting a void method in the gameView so I changed it to String
    {
        this.p1name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter player 1 name","Specify name");
        return p1name;
    }
```

Comment: -1 Yes, these exist. What expression causes it? It's almost always the *same thing* (lack of creating an object) and is "too localized".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should initialized player first..... ?

```
Players player = new Players();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your player isn't initialised at the moment you call:

```
player.enterNameP1(); //Having an error here.
```

To solve this, you have to make sure that the reference `player` actually points to a real instance of Player. This should be done by adding at a logic place in your code this:

```
player = new Players();
```

That is the reason why you got a NullPointerException. When you call a method from a specific object, the object must be initialised (which means that the pointer `player` points to an actual instance of the class `Players`).

Answer (score 1):

You did not instantiated **player**
So it is **null** causing a NPE